# How do I remove the extra zero in the end of each line of the output?

Tags: python

This code generates a pascal triangle:

```
import pprint

def nextRow(cRow):
    cRow.append(0)
    return [cRow[m - 1] + cRow[m + 1] for m in range(len(cRow) - 1)]

def Pascal(n):
    row = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    l = []

    for h in range(n):
        l.append(row)
        row = nextRow(row)

    return l

pprint.pprint(Pascal(5))
```

I am trying to remove the extra zeros without just removing them in the end of the code:

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0]]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: `cRow.append(0)`? why are you doing this if you don't want zero in the output

Comment: `return [row[:-1] for row in l]` instead of `return l`

Answer (score 1):

You can save in `l` the `row` calculated without the last element with `l.append(row[:-1])` instead of `l.append(row)` in the `Pascal` function.

```
import pprint


def nextRow(cRow):
    cRow.append(0)
    return [cRow[m - 1] + cRow[m + 1] for m in range(len(cRow) - 1)]


def Pascal(n):
    row = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    l = []

    for h in range(n):
        l.append(row[:-1])
        row = nextRow(row)

    return l


pprint.pprint(Pascal(5))
```